# How can we search for a string based on a group of records in a dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
 
# data's stored in dictionary
details = {
    'address_id': [111, 111, 111, 111, 222, 222, 222, 222, 333],
    'mydate':['2022-01-24', '2022-01-24', '2022-03-28', '2022-03-28', '2022-01-24', '2022-01-24', '2022-03-28', '2022-03-28', '2022-01-24'],
    'mystring': ['att', 'verizon', 'comcast', 'verizon', 'att', 'verizon', 'att', 'verizon', 'verizon']
}
 
df = pd.DataFrame(details)
df
```

[image]

For a group of identical IDs and changing dates, I want to see if a string is NOT found. Basically, I want to see if 'att' is found in earlier dates and missing in later dates. If 'att' shows up repeatedly in earlier and later dates, I don't care.

The logic is:

att shows up in 111 & 1/24/2022
att is missing in 111 & 3/28/2022

I want to end up with a dataframe like this.

```
    address_id  mydate      mystring    ismissing
0   111         2022-01-24  att         False
1   111         2022-01-24  verizon     False
2   111         2022-03-28  comcast     True
3   111         2022-03-28  verizon     True
4   222         2022-01-24  att         False
5   222         2022-01-24  verizon     False
6   222         2022-03-28  att         False
7   222         2022-03-28  verizon     False
8   333         2022-01-24  verizon     False
```

Comment: "*I want to see if 'att' is found in earlier dates and missing in later dates.*" is unclear, if the first row was not att, would the 3rd and 4th row still be True?

Comment: Attention: the photo is wrong. The last row has to be `False`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combine 2 boolean masks with `and`:

- first ( `id_has_attr` ) tells whether `attr` is present for each id
- second assumes it is present, and checks further conditions

```py
id_has_attr = df.groupby('address_id')['mystring'].transform(
    lambda col: col.str.contains('att').any()
    )
    
df['ismissing'] = df.groupby(['address_id', 'mydate'])['mystring'].transform(
    lambda col: ~ col.str.contains('att').any()
    ) & id_has_attr
```

**Result:**

```py
   address_id      mydate mystring  ismissing
0         111  2022-01-24      att      False
1         111  2022-01-24  verizon      False
2         111  2022-03-28  comcast       True
3         111  2022-03-28  verizon       True
4         222  2022-01-24      att      False
5         222  2022-01-24  verizon      False
6         222  2022-03-28      att      False
7         222  2022-03-28  verizon      False
8         333  2022-01-24  verizon      False
```

Comment: I though this would work perfect, and in my original example, it did work, but I just realized that there is an exception. For any address_id 'att' may show up at least once and drop off, or it may never show up, and I don't care about this. If 'att' doesn't show up for a given address_id, it can't go missing, because it was never there. Please see the last row in my updated original post.

Comment: I just realized that there is a scenario with an exception. So, att may not show up for an address_id, and I want to flag this as 'False'. I think you would have to count the number of occurrences of 'att', per address_id, and if >1, then run your logic.

Comment: @ASH  you are right - the fix is simple - just do 2 operations, and use `and`